# variables inside of $.ajax({...});

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, foreach

I have a foreach loop (php) and i want jquery to post data for each `$value`.
When i create variable
 `var description = $('#<?php echo $value;?>').val();`

and `alert(description);` it works fine, but when i'm trying to use it inside of  `$.ajax({.... });` 
 it shows only the first value.

Why's that?

Code:

```
$('#edit_<?php echo $bid;?>').click(function(){
<?php 
foreach($Languages as $key => $value){  
?>
        var description = $('#<?php echo $value;?>').val();
        alert(''+description+' - <?php echo $value;?>'); // <-- HERE ir alerts the right value 
        $.ajax({
            url: "sqlx.php",
            data: "description="+ description +"&file=<?php echo $image; ?>&client=<?php echo $client; ?>&kategory=<?php echo $xkatid; ?>&language=<?php echo $value;?>", // <-- in this line it sends only first $value
            type: "post",
            success: function(){
                $('#ok<?php echo $bid;?>').fadeIn(100);
                $('#ok<?php echo $bid;?>').fadeOut(1000);
                window.setTimeout(function() {
                $(".xclose<?php echo $bid;?>").trigger('click');
                }, 800);

            }
        });
<?php } ?>
return false;
    });
```

Comment: Post your code, otherwise we can't help.

Comment: Do not mix PHP and JavaScript functionality, it will only lead to confusion. Print data objects with PHP to JS variables, and then write everything in JS.

Comment: The data variable in the ajax() method must embed the data as an object in `{}`. You can always use the HEREDOC syntax to embed Javascript code inside PHP, it's more readable this way.

Comment: Why is `$bid` the same all over the loop? Every of your ajax callbacks will fade and trigger clicks on the same element.

Comment: so if you have 15 values, when user clicks edit_xxx it will send 15 ajax requests? Do you want to put all the values into 1 ajax request?

Comment: i want to do 15 ajax requests

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you are looping in the server side there is a duplicate var definition (for `description`)
you better do the loop in javascript

```
  var bid = <? echo json_encode($bid);?>;
  var server_data = <? echo json_encode($Languages);?>;
  $("#edit_"+bid).click(function(){
      for(var i in server_data){
          var value = server_data[i];
          //here your ajax code enters while you have value and bid variables in the javascript
      }
  });
```

EDIT:
just noticed that you also have `image`,`$client` etc. variables - you should apply the same method, first put the values as javascript vars, and then use them inside javascript

Answer (score 0):

put all php vars into javascript vars and loop them in javascript rather than have php genarate the same javascript over and over again.